# Customizing a POST failure message in Flask+jQuery

Tags: jquery, post, flask

A template of my Flask application has a piece of javascript (jQuery) code that once triggered will try to post some data at a given route:

```
var jqxhr = $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT+endpoint,
                   post_data,
                   function() {
                   alert("Yays!"); })
                    .done(function() { ...finalize_client... })
                    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, err) {
                            alert("Our server returned an error\n" + err +
                                  "\n" + textStatus + "\n" +
                                  "Please try again later.");
                          });
        };
```

Server-side the `endpoint` corresponds to a function like

```
@mod.route(endpoint, methods=['POST',])
def validate_post_data():
    ...
    test = validation_function(post_data)
    if test:
        ...finalize_server...
        return render_template(...)
    return ???
```

that checks the validity of `post_data`. Should the validation fail, I'd like to send some message back to the client so that we can know a bit more what went wrong. What should I return so that I can get the `err` and `textStatus` that I need in the js code? I could use a `flask.abort(whatever)`, but that doesn't give me the possibility to customize the message, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flask.abort(http_code)` return just http code, and probably you can't use next code:

```
return u'Your message there', 404
```

because `jqxhr.responseText` and `jqxhr.responseXML` must return empty string or null for error and redirect responses.

You always can try make message by different http error status, but this can have some restrictions and confuse when you have different http status and message.

So you can use 200 http status which will handle `done` jquery ajax method and add to response status codes:

```
var jqxhr = $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT+endpoint, post_data, function() {
   alert("Yays!");
})
.done(function(data) {
    if (data.status === 'ok') {
        //...finalize_client... with data.response 
    } else {
        alert("Our server returned an error\n" + data.error +
              "\n" + data.status + "\n" +
              "Please try again later.");
    }
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, err) {
    alert("Our server returned an error\n" + err +
          "\n" + textStatus + "\n" +
          "Please try again later.");
});
```

and

```
@mod.route(endpoint, methods=['POST',])
def validate_post_data():
    ...
    test = validation_function(post_data)
    if test:
        ...finalize_server...
        return jsonify(status='ok', response=render_template(...))
    return jsonify(status='error', error='not valid data')
```

or just check respnse:

```
var jqxhr = $.post($SCRIPT_ROOT+endpoint, post_data, function() {
   alert("Yays!");
})
.done(function(data) {
    if (data !== 'something wrong') {
        //...finalize_client...
    } else {
        alert("Our server returned an error\n" + data +
              "\n"
              "Please try again later.");
    }
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, err) {
    alert("Our server returned an error\n" + err +
          "\n" + textStatus + "\n" +
          "Please try again later.");
});
```

and

```
@mod.route(endpoint, methods=['POST',])
def validate_post_data():
    ...
    test = validation_function(post_data)
    if test:
        ...finalize_server...
        return response=render_template(...)
    return 'something wrong'
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea. Now that you pointed that a failure should return an empty string with the status code, it makes sense: we should distinguish the cases where `validation_function` returned False (meaning that the POST was actually processed, 'known failure') from the cases where it wasn't called at all (failed POST, syntax error somewhere: 'unknown failure')...